# ArcMap 10.8.1 error creating annotation feature class. General function error

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, annotation, general-function-failure

I have a folder with labels stored in shape format. We use to convert labels into annotations in a second step. All the work is done at a scale of 1:1000.
One of the shapefiles can't be converted into annotations: "error while creating the annotation feature class. General function error."
I see here that the features are not given to the label engine.

Comment: So you have successfully done the conversion with other shapefiles, but this one is a problem?  Does it display correctly in your project?  You may want to check/repair the geometry.  Are you converting it to annotation in a geodatabase?   If so does the layer and geodatabase have matching CRSs?

Comment: Yes, this one is a problem. I repaired the geometry. It will be converted to annotation in a personal geodatabase with matching CRS. Still doesn't work!

Comment: Time for a "kitchen sink" approach?  Look for any odd characters in the labels.  Try it with simple text labels if the ones you have more complex formatting or symbology.  Try it from a new project or another computer.  Try exporting the shapefile to a feature class in your geodatabase, labeling it and then converting that to annotation.  The personal geodatabase is rather old by now perhaps you might try with a file geodatabase?  Try a newer version of ArcMap or if you have it Pro?